# Jquery css is not loading

Tags: jquery

I have this script but this is not working.

```
function checkWindowSize() {

if ( $(window).width() < 100 ) {document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type'text/css' href='style.css'");}
}

$(window).load(checkWindowSize);
$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "style.css"
}).appendTo("head");
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write`... append to `head` instead:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');
```

Also you had a few syntax errors..

In my opinion the best approach to what you are trying to achieve will be [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). and not what you are currently trying.

Comment: because of internet explorer...

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you need to remove the css if the screen is resized to wider than 100px;